# Error: Unexpected "<" <div> while setting up particles css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am setting up particles as a front-end page. Here's my *ParticleSettings.js* code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";

class ParticleSettings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Particles
          height="1000px"
          width="100vw"
          id="tsparticles"
          options={{
            background: {
              color: {
                value: "#0d47a1"
              }
            },
            fpslimit: 60,
            interactivity: {
              detects_on: "canvas",
              events: {
                onClick: {
                  enable: true,
                  mode: "push"
                },
                onHover: {
                  enable: true,
                  mode: "repulse"
                },
                resize: true
              },
              modes: {
                bubble: {
                  distance: 400,
                  duration: 2,
                  opacity: 0.8,
                  size: 40
                },
                push: {
                  quantity: 4
                },
                repulse: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4
                }
              }
            },
            particles: {
              color: {
                value: "#ffffff"
              },
              links: {
                color: "#ffffff",
                distance: 150,
                enable: true,
                opacity: 0.5,
                width: 1
              },
              collision: {
                enable: true
              },
              move: {
                direction: "none",
                enable: true,
                outMode: "bounce",
                random: false,
                speed: 3,
                straight: false
              },
              number: {
                density: {
                  enable: true,
                  value_area: 800
                },
                value: 80
              },
              opacity: {
                value: 0.5
              },
              shape: {
                type: "circle"
              },
              size: {
                random: true,
                value: 5
              }
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ParticleSettings;
```

Here's the error

> error when starting dev server:
> Error: Build failed with 1 error:
> src/ParticleSettings.js:9:4: error: Unexpected "<"

I don't seem to find any syntax error while looking at the code. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Not sure how important this is (like if `height` is required by `Particles`) but you misspelled "height"

Comment: Still, it doesn't solve the problem. I corrected the "height".

Comment: Is your JSX parser (e.g. Babel) set up correctly?